# Where are these traps in the Sanitarium map?

Tags: killing-floor-2

To complete the Yuletide Horror seasonal objectives, one needs to use the "Tentacle Whip" and "Suction Trap" within the Sanitarium new map (already available through the open beta).

Where are these located within the map? I think I used all triggers (and killed zeds in with them), but my counters are still at 0.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have missed them due to the fact that the traps seem to be not initially available, and only become active partway through the round.

> The traps do not become available until the tremor half way through the map. Wave 4ish on a 7 wave map. There will be a earthquake, the seas will become rough, and there will be a giant tentacle monster offshore letting you know they are available.
>
> The trap areas are both outside not far from the front door of the asylum, near the shore. They are activated with switches on either side of the affected area, the suction trap is on the lowlying patio that has waves washing over it after the tremor. The tentacle trap is on the upper patio where all the outdoor tables are.

[[Source]](https://www.reddit.com/r/killingfloor/comments/dt1z3c/a_couple_quick_tips_for_getting_the_trap_kill/)